# Angular keeps redirecting me to login Page when I try to access another Page

Tags: angular, auth-guard

I have a website that it is divided into some ordinary components that can be accessed by any user and one protected component which is shielded by AuthGuard that will redirect user to login page if not logged in.

The problem I am facing here is that if I try to access the url of the component (other than the admin component) I keep getting redirected to the login page.

Example, out of the routes given below if I type the url for forgot password component manually into the browser I will get redirected to login page but however if I create a button on the login page with routerLink set to that same location I am able to access the forgot password component.

Here are my codes-

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './_components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterCustomerComponent } from './_components/register-customer/register-customer.component';
import { StepperComponent } from './_components/registration/stepper/stepper.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent} from './_components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component'
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './_components/reset-password/reset-password.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'customer/register', component: RegisterCustomerComponent},
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
  { path: 'customer-ui/reset-password',component: ResetPasswordComponent},
  { path: 'registration', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: StepperComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

my authguard file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

    constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }

    canActivateChild() {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
          let currentUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
          if (!currentUser) {
            this.authService
              .setCurrentUser()
              .then((res) => {
                currentUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
                if (!currentUser?.data?.customer?.is_registration_completed) {
                  this.router.navigate(['/registration']);
                  resolve(false);
                } else {
                  resolve(true);
                }
              })
          } else if (!currentUser?.data?.customer?.is_registration_completed) {
            this.router.navigate(['/registration']);
            resolve(false);
          } else {
            resolve(true);
          }
        });
      }
}
```

Comment: Where are you maintaining the loggedInUser state? If not in localStorage. Your app will always route to the login page when you manually enter the URL as the app will think that use it not logged in

Comment: share your app module file as well and the complete url that you are trying to access and also have u configured any base-href ?

Answer (score 2):

Try storing the logged in state in a local storage or some where. If not stored it would only redirect to the login page. Here I have provided a sample code for your reference

Auth.component.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null)
      return true;
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['/user/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
  
}
 app Routing module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddProductComponent } from './add-product/add-product.component';
import { AddUserComponent } from './add-user/add-user.component';
import { AdminpageComponent } from './adminpage/adminpage.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './checkout/checkout.component';
import { EditProductComponent } from './edit-product/edit-product.component';
import { EditUserComponent } from './edit-user/edit-user.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ListProductComponent } from './list-product/list-product.component';
import { ListUserComponent } from './list-user/list-user.component';
import { PaymentSuccessComponent } from './payment-success/payment-success.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './user/login/login.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './user/registration/registration.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'/user/login',pathMatch:'full'},
  {
    path: 'user', component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
    ]
  },
  {path:'home',component:HomeComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  {path:'adminpage',component:AdminpageComponent},
  {path:'list-user',component:ListUserComponent},
  { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent },
  { path: 'edit-user', component: EditUserComponent },
  { path: 'list-product', component: ListProductComponent },
  { path: 'add-product', component: AddProductComponent },
  { path: 'edit-product', component: EditProductComponent },
  { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent },
  { path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutComponent },
  { path: 'payment-success', component: PaymentSuccessComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```